# Scroll bar in grid

Tags: css, ag-grid

i have grid with size 300px,if record is more then 10 then vertical scroll bar is displaying, it is fine but same time horizontal scroll bar also displaying, that i don't want to display.
my css class for vertical

```
     .vstyle {
          overflow-y:auto
       }
```

if i do

```
   .hstyle{
    overflow-x:none
   }
```

then horizontal scroll bar is not displaying, but if minimize browser then horizontal scroll is not displaying, because of css but i need to display horizontal scroll bar if browser is minimize any suggestion on this will helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you will need to add a **CSS** `@media` rule for smaller devices or if the width of your screen gets smaller. To do this you can use the **CSS** code below.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
   .hstyle{
       overflow-x: auto !important;
   }
}
```

Just adjust the `max-width` part to whatever width you need it to start scrolling again. Hope this helps.